# Nameservers still old website

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I have a domain  called www.kickassgamekeys.com for which I switched namerservers and it shows that it is updated. When I try to access it form work it takes me to the new server (default opencart theme) but when I access it form home I always get the old website. I always use same laptop. Switch happened about 30h ago.

Maybe someone has any thoughts?

Yes I tried CTRL+F5. I can enter website form my laptop form work, same laptop but at home and I am directed to the old website.

Comment: wait a little longer?

Comment: Have you tried pressing CTRL-F5 in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dig` to find the TTL of the reponse you are observing in your respective location. It's likely that e.g. your home router still has an old cached entry.

```
dig www.kickassgamekeys.com
...
www.kickassgamekeys.com. 14400  IN  CNAME   kickassgamekeys.com.
kickassgamekeys.com.    14385   IN  A   162.212.134.232
...
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
...
```

The `14400` indicates 4 hours of TTL. That shouldn't linger so long.

Take special note of which server gave you that answer. It may have a caching issue. Use

```
dig +trace
```

to get the chain of name servers that are used to resolve your domain name, and check their responses using

```
dig @<DNS resolver IP>
```

to query them directly.

Comment: Emm should I restart my router or reset it so it would flush the dns? I tried flushing trough CMD but no use :/

Comment: If you're out of luck, restarting won't help either. Have you - I dunno - like, *tried* it? Pretty avant garde of me, I know ;-)

Comment: I will try but my ISP has custom firmware in the router so I am trying to call the support. But why is it like that :/

Comment: **Have** you made sure that your router is at fault?

Comment: No I did't but im out of ideas :/

Comment: Reseting the router did't help either... maybe I should wait for one more day.

Comment: You know, there are debugging instructions right there in the answer.

Comment: Its ok I have changed the dns to google and it works. Thank you for your help.